# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start not working

Tags: xampp

error showing

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.0.8-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong. 
XAMPP:  Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/ 
Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":
tail: cannot open '/opt/lampp/logs/error.log' for reading: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

Comment: Maybe this directory is missing or has invalid permissions (no write?) `/opt/lampp/logs/` ?

Comment: Why not install just Apache, PHP etc. as separate native packages as they are meant to be properly installed on Linux system? LAMPP/XAMPP was designed as a Windows bundle providing equivalent functionality to these Linux server packages, and then someone did a strange thing and backported that bundle to Linux. Don't use that; use just native packages as they are meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the "net-tools" and it solved my issue.

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```